# AngularJS service injected in two different app modules, two apps

Tags: angularjs

I have this app module

```
angular
    .module('history.components.genericAddress', ['history.filters']);
    .service('constantsSrv', ConstantsServiceController)
    .service('addressesService', AddressesServiceController)
```

and another one

```
angular
    .module('APP')
    .service('constantsSrv', ConstantsServiceController)
    .service('addressesService', AddressesServiceController);
```

in two diff files and folders, because there are two diff applications.

I have two services that I use in both modules. I want to put in separate file both services and not anymore inside of each module body. Because each module depends on diff app I don't know how what to put in the top of the new file with both services.
One has module('history.components.genericAddress') and another .module('APP').
I ask this question because I want to make a ver 1.5 angular component and to put that component in many apps. Those 2 services are important for the component.
Please someone give me an idea how to do this because I don't know how to make this service file that will work in any app without changing anything.
So my question is only about how module('what to put here') and not how to make the code for services.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. If you have common code you need to reuse among several projects, move `constantsSrv` and `addressesService` to separate module and include it in these projects.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm new in angular and I don;t understand everything yet :). Only for 3 months I use it. I guess u r right. Can you write an example please, from what u said, or use my example how to do what u said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this.
angular
    .module('Service_module')
    .service('service1', function(){});

use in any module like.

  1. angular
    .module('FirstAPP',['Service_module'])

  2. angular
    .module('SecondAPP',['Service_module'])
```